# Find Number of "-" in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find number of "-" in a table,i am using this query but its not working

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Count (*) from try
where DistrictName  = '-'  OR TownName  = '-'  
OR FarmerName = '-' OR Area = '-'"), con);*
```

Also How can i transform this query TO Find Number of "-" in each column?

Comment: Why isn't it working? Can you show some sample data, the expected results, and the results you're getting instead?

Comment: This counts the number of rows where any of those columns are `-`. If a row has multiple columns with `-` it won't count them multiple times. Is that the problem?

Comment: query does execute properly but it isnt counting all the "-" in the table some how .

Comment: Are you going to provide more details, like I asked for?

Comment: If you edit your question I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second question:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN DistrictName  = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Districts,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TownName  = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Towns,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FarmerName = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Farmers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Area = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Areas
FROM try
```

For the first question, try this to get the total number of hyphens across all columns:

```
SELECT
    SUM((CASE WHEN DistrictName  = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN TownName  = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN FarmerName = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN Area = '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Hyphens
FROM try
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a364b/1)

Comment: Also, note the use of capitalisation for keywords in this example - it makes it a lot easier to read and is the generally accepted standard for SQL.

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax  "Select SUM(DistrictName  = '-') DistrictNULLVALUES,SUM(TownName='-') Towns from try"    because it keep on giving me this error  Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: I'm sure. What do you think is wrong with it? The `AS` keyword is optional.

Comment: I fixed a problem with the second query, due to precedence of `=` and `+`. But the first query works fine. See the sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL and not some other DMBS?

Comment: Well i am using Visual Studio 2010 Run the queries on the database in sqlserver2008

Comment: Then why did you tag the question `mysql` instead of `sql-server-2008`? My answer is will work in MySQL, in SQL Server you may need to use a `CASE` expression. I don't use SQL Server, so I can't be sure.

Comment: I've converted it to SQL Server syntax

Comment: There could be spaces before or after the "-", try use RTRIM and LTRIM to take them out.